# Finding the max and min value of a function

Tags: calculus

> Let $y=10+\frac{1}{2}x^2-3x^{\frac{1}{3}}$. Find the maximum and minimum value of $y$ in the closed interval $[-8,8]$.

How should I approach this? I know that for $x>1$,  $x^2>x^{\frac{1}{3}}$.

Comment: Find any *local* extrema inside $(-8,8)$ by setting $y'=0$ and don't forget to additionally check the value of $y$ at $x=\pm 8$.

Comment: an aid http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve+D+%2810%2B0.5x%5E2-3x%5E%281%2F3%29+%2Cx%29%3D%3D0

Comment: Not relevant in this case, but also check the values of $y$ where $y'$ doesn't exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here $y=10+\frac{1}{2}x^2-3x^{\frac{1}{3}}$

Therefore $$\frac{dy}{dx}=x-x^{-\frac{2}{3}}$$
and $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=1+\frac{2}{3}x^{-\frac{5}{3}}$$

At local maxima or local minima, $$\frac{dy}{dx}=0$$
i.e. $$x-x^{-\frac{2}{3}}=0$$
i.e. $$x=1$$

and at $x=1$, $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=1+\frac{2}{3}1^{-\frac{5}{3}}=\frac{5}{3}>0$$

So the function has a local minimum at $x=1$.

Now $y(1)=\frac{15}{2}$, $y(-8)=48$ and $y(8)=36$

So absolute maximum in given interval is $48$ and absolute minimum in given interval is  $\frac{15}{2}$.

Comment: what about $x=0$?

Answer (score 1):

First by extarumum value theorem min/max points exists

Calculate $y'=x-x^{-2/3} $

Find cricitical point x (which is $y'(x)=0$ $x=1$ is critical point and $x=0$ is singular point ($y'(0)$ does not exists)

$y (0)= 10$

$y (1)=15/2$

$y (8)=36$

$y (-8)=48$

This means min point is 15/2 that is $y>15/2$

$10+1/2 x^2-3x^{1/3}> 15/2 $ then

$x^2>6x^{1/3}-5=x^{1/3}+(5x^{1/3}-5)$

But note that $5x^{1/3}-5>0$ for $x>1$

That is

$x^2>x^{1/3} $ for $x>1$

Answer (score 0):

To find points of maxima and minima differentiate the function with respect to x and find the points where the function changes sign that is become positive from negative and vice versa by calculating the roots of the function,plotting them on a number line and checking the sign of function in respective intervals by plugging in the values.If  the function changes sign from positive to negative then the point is local minimum and if it changes from positive to negative then it is the point of local maximum.